# I want to make an infinity loop with two void functions in c++

Tags: c++, function, loops, infinity

I was wondering if there is a way to make an infinity loop the first function will call the second and the second will call the first and so on. Please make a code in C++. Thanks already.

Comment: That sounds like a bad idea, why?

Comment: It is possible. The main question is will you be able to have `tail call optimization` on both functions?  Otherwise, it will not be infinite. Good luck.

Comment: It's maybe meaningful question in "stackoverflow"

Comment: I am interested in why? Also why do you need to two void functions?

Answer (score 3):

```
void foo();
void bar();

void foo(){
    bar();        
    }

void bar(){
    foo();
    }


int main() {
    foo();
    return 1;
    }
```

Not sure what you're trying to achieve here...? except.. **StackOverflow**.. ohhh!

Comment: You beat me to it ;-) except that you will need a main entry point?

Comment: @ShaunBebbers To be honest I'd rather not give any entry point for such a degenerate atrocity, but updated anyway :)

Comment: Does not really work, clang and icc compile this to `int main () {}`. https://godbolt.org/g/7PRTov

Comment: @BaummitAugen right. VS2013 does only compile it in debug, and warns me I'm an idiot in release. :)

Comment: Nobody said the functions had to be empty. Touch a volatile or something.

Comment: @AlexG - you need a return value on the `int main()` function so that it grac... oh wait!

Comment: @ShaunBebbers No you don't, even when the program does terminate.

Comment: Hm, how to define "infinity"??? According to my definitiion, this solution surely is not infinite, unless one provides an architecture with infinite memory (oh: where to buy such one? I might be interested in...). On the other hand: a simple `for(;;);` won't run infinitely either as at some point far in the future, hardware will certainly fail due to obsolescence...

Comment: @BaummitAugen - I know ;-)

Comment: Couldn't one also use a `do...while()` or a simples `while()` loop to achieve more or less the same result?

Comment: @Aconcagua Infinite memory isn't required if the compiler does tail-call optimization!

Comment: You have UB BTW for empty infinite loop.

Comment: @cdhowie Good point...